# Deserialize nested XML with dynamic fields

Tags: java, jaxb, liferay, xml-serialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have the following XML-Data, generated by liferay-Portal 6.2 for journal-articles:

```
<root available-locales="de_DE" default-locale="de_DE">
<dynamic-element name="Begriff" index="0" type="text" index-type="keyword">
    <dynamic-content language-id="de_DE"><![CDATA[Transition]]></dynamic-content>
</dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element name="Abkürzung" index="0" type="text" index-type="keyword">
    <dynamic-content language-id="de_DE"><![CDATA[]]></dynamic-content>
</dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element name="Synonyme" index="0" type="text" index-type="keyword">
    <dynamic-content language-id="de_DE"><![CDATA[]]></dynamic-content>
</dynamic-element>
<dynamic-element name="Text" index="0" type="text_area" index-type="keyword">
    <dynamic-content language-id="de_DE"><![CDATA[<p>...</p>
<p>Beispielsweise wird d...</p>]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

How can I get a POJO from that XML using Jackson-Annotation

I started with something like the following:

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class BlogEntryContent implements Serializable {

@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "dynamic-element")
private List<DynamicElement> dynamicElement= new ArrayList<>();

// Constructors
 public BlogEntryContent() {
 }  

//Getters an Setters
...
```

and the class **DynamicElement**:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class DynamicElement implements Serializable {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "dynamic-content")
    private List<DynamicContent> dynamicContent = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructors
    public DynamicElement() {
    }

    public DynamicElement(List<DynamicContent> dynamicContent) {

        this.dynamicContent = dynamicContent;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    ...
```

But that does not really work :-(

Comment: _does not really work_ (TM) ... - can you be more specific?

Comment: I do not get an error! I get one empty Object dynamicElement! That’s it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pratik directed me to the right way.
The correct code looks like following:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
public class BlogContent {
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "dynamic-element")
List dynElem;

//Constructor
...

//Getters
...

}
```

Important is to set the rootname with **@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")** and to set the **JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)**, because there is no wrapper in the xml !
@XmlRootElement(name = "root") works also!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give rootElement name in  `@XmlRootElement` annotation for `BlogEntryContent` class. Here it is unable to identify root element of XML data.

try to use like::
`@XmlRootElement(name = "root")`. It will work.